# How to send output of -XshowSettings:vm to stdout in java command

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Running `java -XshowSettings:vm -version` gives:

```
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 247.50M
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

But its being printed on stderr. I don't care about `-version`, but how can I print output of `-XshowSettings:vm` to stdout?

I checked the code https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/launcher/LauncherHelper.java#L152 and this function has an option: `printToStderr` and it says: `printToStderr: choose between stdout and stderr` but I am not sure how to set it from command line?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect it to stdout: `java -XshowSettings:vm -version 2>&1`, and `-version` is required here for `-XshowSettings` will `continues`(see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html)).

```
-XshowSettings:category

    Shows settings and continues. Possible category arguments for this option include the following:
```

Comment: To whom it may concern: when running a Java process inside a Docker container, the "docker logs <container_name>" command will yield both OUT and ERR in the same stream.